# AWS Device Farm currently supports XCTest on iOS 10.3.3 and below

Tags: ios, automated-tests, xctest, aws-device-farm

I'm trying to setup AWS Device Farm to run some automated tests on an iOS app. I'm getting this error when trying to pick a device pool to run on:

`AWS Device Farm currently supports XCTest on iOS 10.3.3 and below`

Am I doing something wrong with my build / device pool or does AWS Device Farm really only support a (soon to be) 2 year old operating system?

EDIT: Screenshot of the issue

[image: Your app is incompatible with 4 out of 5 devices in the selected pool]

Comment: Looks like @NikofTime might have some knowledge of this?

Comment: Would you be able to add a screenshot of the message from the web console? I believe that error message is regarding the device host that runs the tests. I believe if you use XCUI tests instead this doesn't happen because it uses a MacOS host machine whereas the XCTest option may use a Linux host machine.

Comment: @jmp updated with screenshot

Comment: Yes, that error is what thought. It's because of the device host machine being used. I believe they're in the process of updating the device host as the appium device host for iOS uses a Mac OS now.  I believe the XCUI tests should use a Mac OS now so that should support iOS 11.

Comment: @jmp I'm not familiar with XCUITests. Can you run regular XCTests as part of a UI test?

Comment: Yes. XCTests can be a part of UI test.

Comment: XCTests that test application APIs can't run as part of an XCUITest, so there is no real point to running XCTests in an XCUITest. Essentially AWS device farm is crippled for any kind of unit/integration testing until this is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.
Unfortunately, we do not have plans to add support for XCTest on the latest OS versions in the near future.

XCUI Tests are fully supported on Device Farm and you should be able to make XCTest calls from within an XCUI test. That would be suggested way forward.
The AWS Forums and announcements sections is the best place to be up to date on any changes on this front.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What do you mean "you should be able to make XCTest calls form within an XCUITest"? It's my understanding that app APIs can't be called from XCUITests because they run in a different process.